# getting elements in an array1 that are not in array2

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization

Main Problem

What is the better/pythonic way of retrieving elements in a particular array that are not found in a different array. This is what I have;

```
idata = [np.column_stack(data[k]) for k in range(len(data)) if data[k] not in final]
idata = np.vstack(idata)
```

My interest is in performance. My `data` is an (X,Y,Z) array of size (7000 x 3) and my `gdata` is an (X,Y) array of (11000 x 2)

Preamble

I am working on an octant search to find the n-number(e.g. 8) of points (+) closest to my circular point (o) in each octant. This would mean that my points (+) are reduced to only 64 (8 per octant). Then for each `gdata` I would save the elements that are not found in `data`.

[image]

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
from collections import defaultdict

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
data = pd.read_excel(file_path)
data = np.array(data, dtype=np.float)
nrow, cols = data.shape

file_path1 = filedialog.askopenfilename()
gdata = pd.read_excel(file_path1)
gdata = np.array(gdata, dtype=np.float)
gnrow, gcols = gdata.shape

N=8  
delta = gdata - data[:,:2]
angles = np.arctan2(delta[:,1], delta[:,0])
bins = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 9)
bins[-1] = np.inf  # handle edge case
octantsort = []

for j in range(gnrow):    
    delta = gdata[j, ::] - data[:, :2]
    angles = np.arctan2(delta[:, 1], delta[:, 0])
    octantsort = []

    for i in range(8):
        data_i = data[(bins[i] <= angles) & (angles < bins[i+1])]
        if data_i.size > 0:
            dist_order = np.argsort(cdist(data_i[:, :2], gdata[j, ::][np.newaxis]), axis=0)
            if dist_order.size < npoint_per_octant+1:
                [octantsort.append(data_i[dist_order[:npoint_per_octant][j]]) for j in range(dist_order.size)]
            else:
                [octantsort.append(data_i[dist_order[:npoint_per_octant][j]]) for j in range(npoint_per_octant)]
            final = np.vstack(octantsort)

    idata = [np.column_stack(data[k]) for k in range(len(data)) if data[k] not in final]
    idata = np.vstack(idata)
```

Is there an efficient and pythonic way of doing this do increase performance in the last two lines of the code?

Comment: example/simulated data, typical/max dataset size would help more than showing file reading code

Comment: As for getting better performance, try making `final` a `set`. Sets can be searched in O(1) time.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code correctly, then I see the following potential savings:

- dedent the `final = ...` line
- don't use `arctan` it's expensive; since you only want octants compare the coordinates to zero and to each other
- don't do a full `argsort`, use `argpartition` instead
- make your octantsort an "octantargsort", i.e. store the indices into data, not the data points themselves; this would save you the search in the last but one line and allow you to use `np.delete` for removing
- don't use `append` inside a list comprehension. This will produce a list of `None`s that is immediately discarded. You can use `list.extend` outside the comprehension instead
- besides, these list comprehensions look like a convoluted way of converting `data_i[dist_order[:npoint_per_octant]]` into a list, why not simply cast, or even keep as an array, since you want to `vstack` in the end?

Here is some sample code illustrating these ideas:

```
import numpy as np

def discard_nearest_in_each_octant(eater, eaten, n_eaten_p_eater):
    # build octants
    # start with quadrants ...
    top, left = (eaten < eater).T
    quadrants = [np.where(v&h)[0] for v in (top, ~top) for h in (left, ~left)]
    dcoord2 = (eaten - eater)**2
    dc2quadrant = [dcoord2[q] for q in quadrants]
    # ... and split them
    oct4158 = [q[:, 0] < q [:, 1] for q in dc2quadrant]
    # main loop
    dc2octants = [[q[o], q[~o]] for q, o in zip (dc2quadrant, oct4158)]
    reloap = [[
        np.argpartition(o.sum(-1), n_eaten_p_eater)[:n_eaten_p_eater]
        if o.shape[0] > n_eaten_p_eater else None
        for o in opair] for opair in dc2octants]
    # translate indices
    octantargpartition = [q[so] if oap is None else q[np.where(so)[0][oap]]
                          for q, o, oaps in zip(quadrants, oct4158, reloap)
                          for so, oap in zip([o, ~o], oaps)]
    octantargpartition = np.concatenate(octantargpartition)
    return np.delete(eaten, octantargpartition, axis=0)
```